# how to control elements dynamically added to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, ajax

It's a fairly serious problem for me, because I do not know how to program if it takes more than using simple jquery or ajax codes.

To sum up my situation, first of all, I start by saying that I am using a CMS called XE, which is quite similar to wordpress.
(see the link : https://github.com/xpressengine/xe-core even though English isn't supported for documents)

As you can see, the following link is a board that's built using this XE CMS.

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/htmlcss

XE uses its own $function to call document

for example, this is the code from the page i linked above, that opens an article when click on the title of each articles

```
<a href="{getUrl('document_srl',$document->document_srl, 'listStyle',
 $listStyle, 'cpage','')}"><strong>{$document->getTitle()}</strong></a>
```

It worked all fine, until I decided to add this ajax jquery plugin called infinite scrolling js.

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Because this js plugin adds articles dynamically into the DOM, as you can see it on my website, the rest of the articles-except just the one first article- are not opening up, when i click on the thumbnails. (it might open up the layer itself, but it does not provide the exact document address given by the CMS - notice if you click on the '3' item, it still shows '4' item on the div)

below is the scripts I use in order to : open a layer that contains article, close the layer, and to load contents (articles) into the opened layer.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.list_content_link', function() {
        jQuery('.list_content_container').toggleClass('show');


 jQuery.post('{getUrl('document_srl',$document->document_srl, 'listStyle', $listStyle, 'cpage','')}', function(pageContent) {

        jQuery(".loader_container").empty().html('<div class="loader"><div class="loader-inner line-scale-pulse-out-rapid"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>');

    jQuery('.list_content').load('{getUrl('document_srl',$document->document_srl, 'listStyle', $listStyle, 'cpage','')} .board_container');
    });        
});

    jQuery('body').on('click', '.list_content_container', function() { jQuery('.list_content_container').removeClass('show');

});
});`
```

I have already asked this question to one of the developers of this CMS, but only thing he said was, it has to be done by

jQuery.post or jQuery.load only using JS, 
not using php or XE specific codes, as the  'getUrl( ... $document->document_srl ... ) ' gets interpreted in the server and the client cannot provide any information.

Can any one see what the problem im having?

If any information you request, i can provide you to fix this problem once and for all.
I would appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: oh. lol..............

Answer (score 0):

use 'document' insted of 'body'
jQuery(documnet).on('event name', '.list_content_link', function()